# Show the live students who join the tutor class room in flask using socket io

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I want to show the student list to the tutor dashboard who join the online class of that tutor. I am not able to show them by different room.

client side code:

```
stu_name="{{current_user.first_name}}";
socket.emit('join', {room: room,student_name:stu_name});
```

Server side code:

```
@socketio.on('join', namespace='/test')
def join(message):
  join_room(message['room'])
  session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
  message="{0} is in room {1} ".format(message['student_name'],message['room'])
  emit('my_response2',{'chat_msg': message}, room=message['room'])
```

Message show to the tutor is:

```
socket.on('my_response2',function(msg){
    $('#live-student-list').append(msg.chat_msg);
 })
```

Comment: From simple to complex. Have you tried a simple signal with some static data? What is the client side? A browser? Is the signal fired but the data is missing, incorrect, etc?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable help. Problem is solved.